# Cannot connect to server using Enter-PSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm quite new to PowerShell and am trying to write a script that connects to our web server from our db server and pulls a file across. Unfortunately I'm hitting hurdles straight out of the gate with the following error when trying to use the Enter-PSSession cmdlet:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkp00.jpg

I can confirm that PowerShell on the web server is set up and ready to receive connections:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW2LV.jpg

I am at a loss as to what to check now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Just to confirm, I am able to RDP into the web server from the db server fine.

Comment: do a `test-wsman` against that server?

Comment: Hi, I just tried that, and got the below:

PS C:\Users\RIDeveloper> Test-WSMan
Test-WSMan : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859046" Machine="37
2567-web2"><f:Message>The WinRM client cannot complete the operation within the time specified. Check if the machine na
me is valid and is reachable over the network and firewall exception for Windows Remote Management service is enabled.
</f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:11
+ Test-WSMan <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationExce...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using domain joined Machines and domain user accounts you will need to add the destination server to your trusted hosts list

```
Set-Item WSMan:\LocalHost\Client\TrustedHosts\ -Value "192.168.100.234"
```

You should check if you have machines add first

```
Get-Item WSMan:\Localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

if you do you will need to append the new ipaddress or the pervious values will be overwritten.

You should also check the network profiles on both machines. Powershell remoting will not work with the network profile set to Public.

EDIT:

You need to run: Enable-PsRemoting not winrm qc to allow powershell remoting
winrm is only half the puzzle.

Comment: Actually, WinRM qc enables PS remoting and creates a firewall rules. I prefer using Enable-PSRemoting myself, but the command he is using is correct.

Comment: WinRM is Windows Remote Management Service, WinRM qc will start the service, open the firewall port and start the listener. This is all required in order to allow Powershell remoting to a machine but enabling WinRM will not enable Powershell remoting. Since Server 2012 WinRM is enabled by default when you install the OS. This will allow connection via Server Manager or RSAT for example but you will find that you still have to run the Enable-PSRemoting in order to connect via Powershell Remoting.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello. dont Have a reputation to post a comment, so read some info
>   heare.  If you have a domain you can try to do this: In the group
>   policy mmc: Policies/Administrative Templates /Windows
>   Components/Windows Remote Management (WinRM)/WinRM Service
>       Allow Remote Server management through WinRM
>       Set the Policy to Enabled.
>       Set the IPv4 and IPv6 filters to *

[enter link description here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/24/an-introduction-to-powershell-remoting-part-two-configuring-powershell-remoting/)

> Or you can try to do something like this:
>
> On local host and remote PC

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force| Out-Null
winrm qc -q| Out-Null
```